# Getting error in Media Player. MediaPlayer(8743): Error (-38,0)

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing Media Player. I have the URL and am setting up the Media Player like. But i am getting follwing errors:

```
E/MediaPlayer(8743): stop called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer(8743): error (-38, 0)
```

The code is:

```
      public void onPlayClick(View view) {
    Object obj = view.getTag();
    if (obj != null && obj.getClass() == RowItem.class) {

        final RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) obj;
        if (!rowItem.mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            invalidatePlayButtons(rowItem.mPosition);

            try {
                rowItem.mPlayer.reset();
                rowItem.mPlayer.setDataSource(rowItem.mTrack.getAboluteFilePath());
                Log.d("RINGTONE","File path = "+rowItem.mTrack.getAboluteFilePath());
                rowItem.mPlayer.prepare();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            rowItem.mPlayer.start();
            rowItem.mPlayer
                    .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.stop();
                            rowItem.mPlayButton
                                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        }
                    });
            rowItem.mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            rowItem.mProgressBar.setMax(rowItem.mPlayer.getDuration());
            showAnimation(rowItem);
            rowItem.mTrack.setPlaying(false);
        } else {
            invalidatePlayButtons(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -38 is `INVALID_OPERATION`, and state 0 is `MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_ERROR`, which implies that something has gone wrong even before you call `stop()`.

Comment: Yes i know but still i am not getting the error, Please any body help me ....

Comment: Go through the logs. There ought to be something there eariler related to your MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using media player you should also release your media player use this code

```
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(FallAnimationActivity.this,
                    sounds[fakeindex]);
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    mp.release();// you missed this code
                }
            });
```